# Flask app port refusing connection on ec2

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have a flask app that I am depoying on an EC2 instance. The app starts just fine:

```
ubuntu@ip-something:~/webservices$ python service/texting_service.py 
 * Serving Flask app "texting_service" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 146-396-474
```

When I `ssh` into this EC2 instance and call the service using `localhost`, it returns the expected response. However, when I try to call this service from outside the EC2 instance using the instance's public IP address I see this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2.instance.ip.address port 8080: Connection refused
```

I confirmed that I have opened the ingress port `8080` for the security group attached to this EC2 instance. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. If you do not pass the parameter `host` with value `0.0.0.0` in the `app.run()` function, the app is not visible externally. Doing the following resolved my issue:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: this is what i was missing. Thanks